# Linux script to check if DNS have the same IP like the one next to it in the same list

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I've got a list of DNS and IP adresses in this format:

> DNS IP
>
> DNS IP
>
> DNS IP

And I need to do a script which do `dig +short DNS` and check if it has the same IP as the one next to it, and that with all the document. The idea is that if it's the same, it returns a message like `$DNS and $IP match` if are the same, or an error message if they doesn't.

I've tried with `awk '{ DDD=$(dig +short $1); if ( $DDD == $2 ); then; print "'$DDD' and '$2' match."; fi }' all.log`

But the result is:

> (space) and (space) match.
>
> (space) and (space) match.
>
> (space) and (space) match.

Comment: This is not an answer to your question but I did several bash-scripts in the last years. I am sure that is possible with bash but I also think it is a bit to complex for it. I would do it with perl. There I think you have better mechanics to do that. And I also think there is perl anywhere on todays Linux systems.

Comment: You seem to mix `awk` and `bash` syntax. For an example how to read values from a file, see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001#Field_splitting.2C_whitespace_trimming.2C_and_other_input_processing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple answer using only bash:

```
while read DNS IP; do
  DDD=$(dig +short "$DNS")
  if [ "$DDD" = "$IP" ]; then
    echo "'$DDD' and '$IP' match."
  else
    echo "'$DDD' and '$IP' do not match."
  fi
done < all.log
```

*Be warned that `dig +short NAME` command can return more than one line as a result, and in this case the script will not work...*

Comment: @EdMorton: thanks, corrected my answer, much better now... Thanks for your suggestion, I didn't know about that bash read syntax... :-)